# MySQL Master/Slave replication using jdbc url

Tags: mysql, tomcat, jdbc, replication, mysql-connector

We have created MySQL replication. We have one master and two slaves. Everything is working fine on the mysql shell.When we insert new data in the master, data replicated to all slaves.

But, when we make request from tomcat using jdbc url all requests come to the master.No queries come to slaves.

We use spring 3.0, hibernate, mysql 5.0.95 and mysql-connector-java-5.1.12.jar

```
Driver : com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationDriver
jdbcUrl : jdbc:mysql:replication//master_ip:3306,slave_1_ip:3306,slave_2_ip:3306/database_name?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&autoReconnect=true&roundRobinLoadBalance=true
```

What is wrong here? Do we miss something on the url?

Answer (score 0):

Silly question perhaps, but are you setting Connection.setReadOnly(true) when you only need to read data?

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-master-slave-replication-connection.html

Comment: On the configuration file we use readOnly=true but it is still not working.

Comment: Have look at this, it looks like what you are experiencing http://www.dragishak.com/?p=307

Comment: link is broken, answer lost?